# Ember Two Way Binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js, data-binding

Using Ember 2.0. I have an object that I want to bind with a set of inputs. The keys in the object are not known until run time. Here is what I have:

JS

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  form: {},
  fields: Ember.computed(function() {
   //Dynamically gets list of fields as array
   return fields;
  })
});
```

HBS

```
{{#each fields as |field|}}
  {{field.title}} - {{input type="text" value=(mut (mergeHelper "form." field.title))}}
{{/each}}
```

MERGEHELPER

```
export function mergeHelper(params) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    result+=params[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

The problem I have is when I go to edit the input I get the following error: "Uncaught Error: Stream error: setValue not implemented". What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You are binding value to the result of a helper, so it won't work. I think you'll need a computed property using the get/set syntax.

Comment: You can also try using the `get` helper to dynamically fetch the property.

Answer (score 0):

The binding should work fine changing the property of the array returned by the computed property.  This example works fine for me in `ember 2.2`

---

`fields: Ember.computed(function() {
    return [{ title: 'something' }, { title: 'something' }, { title: 'something' }];
  }),`

---

`fields:
{{#each fields as |field|}}
  {{field.title}} - {{input type="text" value=field.title}}
{{/each}}`

---

notice how when changing the last input value the label changes as well.
[image]